# Facebook replaces #!v URLs by "_escaped_fragment_" when sharing

Tags: ajax, facebook, url, gwt, mvp

I am trying to share this URL from my app on Facebook:
http://www.example.com/#!v;id=NH1NlYov3bKJ

However, it is automatically replaced by:
http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=v%3Bid%3DNH1NlYov3bKJ

This URL is wrong and it is not retrieven the right title, description and pictures from the webpage. What can I do? Thanks

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why does your URL contains the sequence `#!`? Can you change it? Because ajax content is not crawlable, the sequence is part of the (Google) specification to make this content crawlable, and most of the internet big fishes are using it by now.

How does it works? Lets say you have a url like `www.example.com/folder#!id=4`. It means some content of the url is delivered by ajax, and it depends of the information id=4, called hash. The Google crawler will try to read the page `www.example.com/folder?_escaped_fragment_=id=4` instead, where, according to the specification, the crawler expects to find a no ajax version of the same page.

I don't like it at all, but it works, and that is why Twitter, Facebook, Groveshark and a lot of other big fishes are using the specification. So when you share a grooveshark song in the facebook (a 100% ajax page), facebook knows where to find the non ajax version of the same page. But because of that Facebook is also trying to change your urls.

Answer (score 5):

Stop using `#!` or handle escaped-fragment queries as per Google's guidelines.

---

See [Google's "Full Specification" for Webmasters](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification):

> Each URL that contains a hash fragment beginning with the exclamation mark is considered a **#! URL**. Note that any URL may contain at most one hash fragment. Each pretty (#!) URL has a corresponding ugly (_escaped_fragment_) URL, which is derived with the following steps:
>
> - The hash fragment becomes part of the query parameters.
> - The hash fragment is indicated in the query parameters by preceding it with _escaped_fragment_=
> - Some characters are escaped when the hash fragment becomes part of the query parameters. These characters are listed below.
> - All other parts of the URL (host, port, path, existing query parameters, and so on) remain unchanged.

In this case, Facebook is doing this pretty-to-ugly (or client-dynamic-to-crawlable) step initially. Remember, the `_escaped_fragment_` form *should result in a repeatable snapshot*.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky I know, but I'm about to use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to catch _escaped_fragement_ urls.  In my case this is because I've made a pure .html/.js single-page webapp and I need to catch when a search engine wants a snapshot, but you could use the same tech to rewrite the ugly _escaped_fragment_ into the right format for your site.

Answer (score -1):

One other idea would be to push the correct url through a shortcut service before you share it, such as http://goo.gl/

Comment: This will probably not work: shortcut services simply do a redirect, Facebook will probably rewrite the redirected URL as well.